# Is it possible to keep Whatsapp from saving *outgoing* sent videos to Camera Roll?

Tags: iphone, ios, photos, video, whatsapp.app

When I record and send an *outgoing* video through Whatsapp it automatically saves a copy (duplicate) to my Camera Roll. This is a pain because I do not want them saved.

*Is there a way to turn off automatic saving of outgoing video to Camera Roll?*

Note: This is **different** than Whatsapp automatically saving *incoming* media to Camera Roll, which can easily be turned off in the settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This is not a supported feature as of March 20, 2021 per Whatsapp customer service.** See screenshot.

[image: Screenshot of Whatsapp customer service response]